# Javascript Function and const array

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a problem with my exercise:

```
const negativeNumbers = [];
function extractNegativeNumbers(numbers) {
    if (numbers<0){
        console.log("It's negative number")
    } else {
        console.log("It's not negative number")
    }
}
```

I don't know how to append my function's result to const array. Which operator should I use to do this ?

Comment: Hey sepson what is the expected argument to your functtion it's an array right?!

Comment: const negativeNumbers = [];

function extractNegativeNumbers(numbers) {
    // append any negative numbers found in the numbers array 
    // into the negativeNumbers array constant variable above
}     i have something like this as an exercise

Comment: I knew it from the beginning but I just wanted to be sure, happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

**Edit**: If your `numbers` parameter is an array rather than a single value, then use the following to check each item and append it:

```
const negativeNumbers = [];
function extractNegativeNumbers(numbers) {
    numbers.forEach(num => {
        if (num < 0) {
            console.log("It's negative number");
            negativeNumbers.push(num);
        } else console.log("It's not negative number");
    });
}
```

You don't use an operator in this case, instead you use the built-in function push which belongs to the `Array` object.

Some of the others mentioned using `let` or `var` instead, but neither is necessary because array objects are mutable. What this means is that updating the items of an array doesn't actually change the value of the variable, as the variable is still set to the same array object (regardless of what the array contains). In this case, all that adding the `const` keyword does is prevent you from reassigning the variable `negativeNumbers` to a different value

Comment: Something is wrong. I dont have idea where. There is a comunicate : " Expected [ ] to equal [.-1, -2, -10].

Comment: @sepson you'll have to give me some more context. What code are you running that produces that error, because nothing in the snippet you provided would produce such an error. Is this a test case you are checking?

Comment: @awarrier99 I think he expects an array as argument to the function and not just a number, that way `numbers < 0` will return `false` and his array stays empty instead of filled with negative numbers, that's the most resonable cause to his last comment, pls edit your post to iterate over the array he's expecting!

Comment: @sepson as pointed out, I thought your `numbers` argument was a single value rather than an array. If `numbers` is also an array, refer to my updated answer on how to compare those values

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not make sense. If it's to receive an array called numbers and append to your const array, then it should be:

```
function extractNegativeNumbers(numbers) {
    for (let num of numbers)
        if (num < 0)
            negativeNumbers.push(num);
}
```

Note, that even though your array is constant, its items can be changed. `const` prevents you from reassigning values for your variable, but not from adding items to your array. Also, if `negativeNumbers.push(num);` is not to your taste, you can use `negativeNumbers[negativeNumbers.length] = num;` instead.

Comment: O, there is a good solution.. i didn't have idea that i can use "let" in this form.. thank You

Comment: But i don't understeand in 100% why is that is good. On my eye it should be. const negativeNumbers = [];
function extractNegativeNumbers(numbers) {
    if (numbers>0){
        negativeNumbers.push(numbers);
    }
}          i dont understand the difference between these two :(

Comment: @sepson an array contains multiple values. When using the expression `numbers < 0`, you are trying to compare a **single** value (which doesn't make sense in this case because `numbers` is an array, not a number) to 0, rather than each value of the array `numbers`. What Lajos has done is iterate over each element of the array (as in each value that the array contains) and individually compare each value to 0

Comment: @sepson Awarrier99 is right. Your ```numbers``` parameter suggests plurality, that is, you have more than a single number. This is why my answer assumes this is an array. Awarrier99's answer had an initial version where a single item has been handled. His edited answer also deals with an array. In essence, I think the answer must show you how you can add negative numbers to your const array. So, to answer your question, the difference between my code and the one you have shown is that yours handles a number for negativity, while mine handles the numbers of an array for negativity.

Comment: Aha, so in simple word's: I show this "-1" and you show this: "-1,-2,-3 etc." It that correct ?

Comment: @sepson it is correct indeed. It's the difference between singular and plural, the difference between -1 and [-1, -2, -3], as you have pointed out.

Comment: Could you help me with with the opposite exercise with "let" ?

Comment: @sepson by "opposite exercise" do you mean writing a function which tests a single number to be negative, using let and adding it to your const array?

Comment: @LajosArpad let largestString;

function findLargestString(strings) {
    // set largestString to point to the 
    // longest string found in the strings array passed in
} I have somethig like that to do.. i tried do this analogy to exercise with const but its wrong. i have no idea how to do this :( After "//" its the name of exercise

Comment: @sepson I would be glad to solve it if you ask another question and let me know about it in the comment section. Here in the comment section it's not ideal to write a function, but I can do it for you. If not now, then when I wake up.

Comment: I will be very thankful because i am so tired for coding right now . so if you can write for me this morning i will appreciate that

Comment: @sepson it will be something like ```var largestString = ""; for (let currentString of strings) if (largestString.length < currentString.length) largestString = currentString;``` But you can ask this as a question to make sure it will be more elegant. But you have the solution in this comment for the case when I'm coming here a little bit later.

Comment: Unfortunetly there is something wrong.. error says:" largestString should be set to the largest string passed in. Expected undefined to equal "computers."

Comment: @sepson if you pasted my code into a function and you have a ```let largestString;``` before the function, then my ```var largestString``` shadows your variable. In that case there are two variables with the same name and even though the correct value is found out in the for cycle I have given, it's set to a local variable in the function's scope, rather than to the variable where your professor expects the value. Please create a new question on stackoverflow and provide a link to that here. It's not ideal to ask and answer separate questions in the comment section.

Comment: @LajosArpad I cut solution to this : "for (let currentString of strings) 
   largestString = currentString;" and its done. Could You tell me difference without if and with if ?

Comment: @sepson without if largestString will always be overriden, by currentString, which means that it will always end up to be the very last item, regardless of whether it's the longest string. The if in my code ensures that we only override largestString with currentString, if currentString happens to be larger than the largestString we have found so far. You need that ```if```.

Comment: by "it's done" i mean, that computer says "your solution is ok" :D with "if" i unfortunetly had error. thats why i wanted to know why without if its ok but with if not..

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array using let as const is used to declare constants.

```
let negativeNumbers = [];
```

You can use push function to add elements.

```
negativeNumbers.push(number +' is a negative number');
```

For further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: I can't use "let" because its exercise with "const"

Comment: `let` isn't needed here. An array is mutable, so updating the elements of an array doesn't change whether it is a constant or not

Comment: You misunderstand ```const```. Your array is constant, but not its items. You can assign or add items to your const array, you can not reassign your const array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do it

```js
const numbers = [13, 3, -4, 78, -14, 12, -8],
  negativeNumbers = numbers.filter(n => n < 0);

console.log(negativeNumbers);
```